# Recently viewed products not showing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to get the recently viewed products to show on the product page under up-sells.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8050661/3204827) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19268891/3204827) question I added:

```
 <reference name="content">
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

to the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml` file and I added:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>
```

just below

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

in the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file, but no recently viewed products will show up. What am I doing wrong that the recently viewed products won't show?

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout file to this:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
   <reference name="content">
       <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then add this to your view.phtml file like you have it now.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>
```

Comment: Change it where in the layout file

Answer (score 0):

There is a handle for each page apart from default handle which is for all pages.

So first you need to add your block in that handle( you do this in local.xml file )

as stated in above comment:

your XML node related to block

This will result in your block as a child of content block for catalog product view page.
Now getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>  will do for you.

Comment: What handle block do I add to the local.xml file and where is the local.xml file?

Comment: search  <catalog_product_view>  in .xml and you will get idea on what to write and where to write.standard is to write in local.xml or layout xml file